# How do I make a picture as my background in css

Tags: html, css

```
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: url('3.jpg') repeat-y top;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;  
}
```

It's not working for some reason. The image is stored in the same place where my php file is stored. That's why I didn't put images/3.jpg. I even tried it with the images/ and it didn't work.

I'm using Bootstrap; all the css body code is working except the background.

Comment: The URL path is relative from where your CSS file is located. What's your folder structure?

Comment: if you have your css in a folder you need put this : url('../3.jpg')

Answer (score 0):

try this:

css3 way

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

css

```
img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

and more way here:
[csstricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is correct. You likely have a url path problem. Directions to the image are from the CSS file to the image. The code you have written will only work if the image is in the same folder as your CSS file.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are doing your css but the image path needs to be relative to the file containing the css.  To check this you can make a simple img tag with the path and see if the image displays.

```
<img src="img.jpg"> or <img src="path/to/file/img.jpg">
```

Your CSS should work.  If you have an external style sheet (.css file) you will need to import it in the head tag of the page you want to use it in.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/file/style.css">
```

Don't forget that the image path is relative to the file that calls it, even if you import a css file the image should still be relative to the style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for firefox, or the inbuilt devloper tools in Chrome . From this you can inspect elements and see what has been applied. This will help you see if you have a typo in your code anywhere. It will also highlite resources that can't be found. The `net` tab in Firebug is particularly useful in this regard.

I would use [root relative paths](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html) for you image url, this makes the path to the resource indipendant of where the resource is called from.